# Unable to find pytorch==1.11.0 from inside continuumio/miniconda3 Docker container

Tags: python, docker, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to get `pytorch==1.11.0` using the [continuumio/miniconda3:4.12.0](https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/miniconda3) Docker image.

I first run `docker run -i -t continuumio/miniconda3 /bin/bash`. Then, in the container, I run: `conda search -c conda-forge pytorch==1.11.0`. Here's the error:

```
No match found for: pytorch==1.11.0. Search: *pytorch*==1.11.0

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - pytorch==1.11.0

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-aarch64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-aarch64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-aarch64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I then tried `conda config --append channels conda-forge` before running `conda search -c conda-forge pytorch==1.11.0` again. Got the same error.

To test the network connection I ran `conda search pytorch`, so it'd search the default channel for any pytorch package. It's successful:

```
Loading channels: done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel             
pytorch                        1.8.1 cpu_py37he9ab0f8_0  pkgs/main           
pytorch                        1.8.1 cpu_py38he9ab0f8_0  pkgs/main           
pytorch                        1.8.1 cpu_py39he9ab0f8_0  pkgs/main           
pytorch                       1.10.2 cpu_py310h65e219b_0  pkgs/main           
pytorch                       1.10.2 cpu_py37ha034a5a_0  pkgs/main           
pytorch                       1.10.2 cpu_py38ha034a5a_0  pkgs/main           
pytorch                       1.10.2 cpu_py39ha034a5a_0  pkgs/main
```

Curiously, when I run `conda search -c conda-forge pytorch==1.11.0` outside of the container, in my local terminal, it's available:

```
Loading channels: done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel             
pytorch                       1.11.0 cpu_py310h61528c5_1  conda-forge         
pytorch                       1.11.0 cpu_py310h61528c5_2  conda-forge         
pytorch                       1.11.0 cpu_py310he9514b4_0  conda-forge         
pytorch                       1.11.0 cpu_py38h17550ec_1  conda-forge         
pytorch                       1.11.0 cpu_py38h17550ec_2  conda-forge         
pytorch                       1.11.0 cpu_py38h1b6422d_0  conda-forge         
pytorch                       1.11.0 cpu_py39h03f923b_1  conda-forge         
pytorch                       1.11.0 cpu_py39h03f923b_2  conda-forge         
pytorch                       1.11.0 cpu_py39h19aa3d3_0  conda-forge
```

Why's this the case and how do we fix it?

Comment: "*linux-aarch64*" are you intentionally using an ARM image? I'm guessing your system isn't `linux-aarch64`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Current channels" in the error message showing **linux-aarch64** indicates that the Docker image is `arm64`. Conda Forge only added such `pytorch` builds in v1.12.0; the `anaconda` channel does offer some earlier builds, but only up to v1.10.

Otherwise, maybe you didn't actually want an `arm64` Docker image. In that case, one can specify the platform in `docker` CLI with the `--platform` argument, e.g., `--platform=linux/amd64`.

---

P.S. I'd use [a Mambaforge container](https://hub.docker.com/r/condaforge/mambaforge) instead.

Comment: I think you're on the money here. In case anyone is looking for it, we use the `--platform` flag in the `FROM` line of the Dockerfile. Eg: `FROM --platform=linux/amd64 nvidia/cuda:11.3.1-runtime-ubuntu20.04`. Thanks!